# Буквальные символы в регулярных выражениях C++

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет, можно ли в std::regex сделать так, чтобы часть регулярки воспринималась буквально? 
Наподобие Pattern.quote() в java или escape() в C#. Или же надо самому надо менять все метасимволы?

Answer (score 3):

В регулярных выражениях не очень много управляющих символов, поэтому достаточно обычным образом экранировать символы:

```
[ ] \ / ^ $ . | ? * + ( ) { }
```

Делается это очень просто:

```
string escape( string s ) {
    std::regex re ( "[\\[\\]\\/^$.|?*+(){}]" );
    return std::regex_replace (s, re, "\\$0");
};
```

[IDEone](http://ideone.com/K9gcW0)

На входе:

```
[]abc{}
```

на выходе:

```
\[\]abc\{\}
```

Comment: Pattern.quote() как раз и добавляет \Q \E , но увы, такое не работает в std regex . А просто экранировать никак, текст всегда разный

Comment: Простой заменой не решаемо, т.к. не следует экранировать эти символы в `[здесь]`.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание исправлю.

Comment: Эм. Нет. Ничего исправлять не надо. Вы неправильно поняли задачу. Необходимо экранировать часть строки, то есть нужен аналог  Pattern.quote ` из состава JavaSDK.