# регулярные выражения std::regex

Tags: c++, stl, std-regex

Есть строка такого типа:

AnyNameFileC[FORMAT]x64.exe

Нужно получить слово внутри квадратных скобок
Путался сделать безуспешно по такому шаблону:

```
const std::regex pattern("^.*\[([a-zA-Z0-9+])\].*$");
```

Получаю ошибку

warning C4129: '[': unrecognized character escape sequence

warning C4129: ']': unrecognized character escape sequence

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Буквальные символы в регулярных выражениях C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/617527/%d0%91%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f%d1%85-c)

Answer (score 4):

Экранируйте `\`.

```
const std::regex pattern("^.*\\[([a-zA-Z0-9+])\\].*$");
```

Comment: Компилится, но шаблон почему то не ловится

Comment: std::smatch matchFormat;
  if (std::regex_match(installerName, matchFormat, pattern))
   format = matchFormat[1];
Пустую строку возвращает

Comment: разобрался. Шаблон должен быть:
[a-zA-Z0-9_] Забыл про _

Answer (score 1):

Вот так вот:

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const std::string test{"AnyNameFileC[FORMAT]x64.exe"};
    const std::regex pattern{R"(^.*\[(\w*)\].*$)"};
    
    std::smatch match;
    std::regex_match(test, match, pattern);

    std::cout << match[1] << '\n'; 
}
```

Тест https://godbolt.org/z/5hzesv

> FORMAT